# Cygwin not operating after new package install?

Tags: windows-7, cygwin, wget

I installed wget package through setup.exe on my existing Cygwin installation. But the problem is, after rebooting and opening Cygwin, it's not functioning properly. Some simple commands like ls, man, cygcheck are not working now. How do I get it back to working? I think it's a version conflict problem.

Once the setup was completed. I got a warning message and below is the latter part of the setup.log which is related to the warning message.

`2012/10/16 22:06:58 running: d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile /etc/postinstall/man.sh
2012/10/16 22:07:14 abnormal exit: exit code=256
2012/10/16 22:07:14 running: d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile /etc/postinstall/gcc-mingw-core.sh
2012/10/16 22:07:29 abnormal exit: exit code=256
2012/10/16 22:07:29 running: d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile /etc/postinstall/gcc-mingw-g++.sh
2012/10/16 22:07:44 abnormal exit: exit code=256
2012/10/16 22:07:44 running: d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile /etc/postinstall/wget.sh
2012/10/16 22:07:59 abnormal exit: exit code=256
2012/10/16 22:07:59 Changing gid to Administrators`

```
2012/10/16 22:19:00 note: In-use files have been replaced. You need to reboot as soon as possible to activate the new versions. Cygwin may operate incorrectly until you reboot.
```

Comment: And about what are commands like `ls` complaining? What do you mean with version conflict? The warning message after theq setup is normal. I hope you did a reboot right after the setup.

Comment: its 'command not found'. yeah I did a reboot after setup. Now I'm reinstalling the Cygwin with older directory again; hope it will be ok then...

Comment: Is your PATH variable ok? `ls` should be in /bin or /usr/bin. Can you go there and do `echo *`?

Comment: yes it's in usr/bin so echo * should display it. Anyway not I reinstalled it and now its working fine. Thanks a lot for trying to help me out.

Comment: if you have time please have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921249/apt-cyg-where-the-downloaded-files-stored